# Align in same row

Tags: html, css

How to align the below image and box in same row? Image on left and box on right with some space between them.

```
<div id="slideshow" >
    <div id="changeimage">
       <img class="image" src="bafdf1f214f5a800c95ef301234c254a.iix"/>
    </div>

    <div id="newsbox">
        <span class="label label-danger">Latest News</span>
        <div class="group-box">
            <div class="grey-group">    
                <span>Notes:This is a box</span>                
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: there's about 20 ways to skin that cat.  start with `float:left`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @ntgCleaner said: "there's about 20 ways to skin that cat."

This might be one way to achieve this:

```css
#slideshow {
  display: flex;
}

.group-box {
  margin-top: 50px; 
}
```

```html
<div id="slideshow" >
 <div id="changeimage">
   <img class="image" src="//thumb7.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/260389/347420135/stock-photo-top-view-of-architect-drawing-on-architectural-project-347420135.jpg"/>
  </div>

 <div id="newsbox"><span class="label label-danger">Latest News</span>
   <div class="group-box">
       <div class="grey-group">   
          <span>Notes:This is a box</span>                
       </div>
   </div> 
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "float" or "display: inline-block" css selectors to set your elements this way. I belive this simple example will help:

```
<style>
#slideshow{
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
}
#changeimage{
  float: left;
  background: blue;
  width: 40%;
}
#newsbox{
  float: left;
  background: red;
  width: 40%;
}
#separator {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  background: green;
}
.clear{
  clear: both;
}

</style>
<div id="slideshow" >
  <div id="changeimage"><img class="image" src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg"/></div>
  <div id="separator"></div>
  <div id="newsbox"><span class="label label-danger">Latest News</span>
    <div class="group-box">
      <div class="grey-group">   
        <span>Notes:This is a box</span>                
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>
  <div class="clear"> </div>
</div>
```

And here is working example: 
https://jsfiddle.net/ej53b8x2/

If you want to set elements in row maybe you should use some framework like bootstrap or foundation?